# Is it possible to force showing `input type="hidden"`

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, input

I know this seems an insane thing to ask, but sometimes web development requires crazy workarounds and the only other workaround for our situation that I've found is similar, and slightly more stupid still.

So I was wondering if I can force display of `<input type="hidden" />`

I tried these ideas in Chrome but despite them, and despite the browser showing the node with dimensions of 22x22, it still renders nothing.

```
height: 22px;
width: 22px;
appearance: unset;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
```

Comment: No. You cannot.

Comment: Is there some specification that defines it? The rules I'm aware of seem to suggest `appearance` can render it as something different, and the rules of specificity should theoretically allow overriding the user agent styles.

Comment: You've tagged this `javascript`; it's fairly trivial if you can use that. `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=hidden]').forEach(function(element) {
  element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
});`

Comment: A "hidden" input field is not shown. It's the whole point of the input type. It's for things like special values in forms that don't need to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ceejayoz but I was under the impression my workaround specifically required "hidden" (fortunately it does not) -- I'm still interested in a canonical answer for this.

Comment: What you can do is to get the value of that input and show it in a neutral tag. (javascript  insertAfter() )

Comment: `appearance: unset` should result in the same as not having set `appearance`, or not ? You would need [`appearance: none`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#appearance-switching) to apply the ["primitive appearance"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui/#primitive-appearance) _(What is the "primitive appearance" of a element `type=hidden` ?)_, and apply your own styles. But that doesn't work either, e.g. Chrome sets `appearance: none` for the `type="hidden"` element. IMO that is wrong, it should be `appearance: auto`, even if the element is then hidden anyway for other reasons.

Comment: Should the user be able to edit the value of the input element?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `type="hidden"` you can just hide the input by setting `display: none` on the input itself or a parent element. The result of the submitted data is the same.

The only issue (in any case) is that the user can change the value of the input.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  switch(e.submitter.name){
    case 'toggle':
      e.target.id.closest('label').classList.toggle('hide');
      break;
    case 'submit':
      let data = new FormData(e.target);
      console.log([...data.entries()].map(ent => `${ent[0]}: ${ent[1]}`).join('\n'));
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .2em;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
  <label>ID: <input type="text" name="id"></label>
  <label><button name="toggle">Toggle ID</button></label>
  <label><button name="submit">Submit</button></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this isn't relevant to my question.